# How to find the interval that I must restrict $x$ so that $\sqrt[3]{1 - x} - 0.1 < 1 - \frac{1}{3}x < \sqrt[3]{1 - x} + 0.1$ is true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

As Dan points out in the comments, an exact solution will require the cubic formula.  I'm just looking for an approximation.  I've been able to solve the problem with a graphing calculator, but I'm looking for a strategy here that allows me to approximate (however badly) an answer without a calculator.

Comment: Do you want an exact answer, or an approximation?  Because an exact answer will require the cubic formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a step back to what I assume the *actual* question is.

You're given a function $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{1 - x}$, and want to find a straight-line approximation $g(x) = ax + b$ near $x = 0$.

Differentiating gives:

$$f'(x) = -\frac{1}{3}(1 - x)^{-2/3}$$

From which $f'(0) = -\frac{1}{3}$.  Thus, the tangent line at the point $(0, 1)$ is $g(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{3}x$.

You want to find an interval over which the approximation is “good”, i.e., $\left| g(x) - f(x) \right| < 0.1$.

A simple *approximate* bound for $x$ can be found with a second-degree Taylor series: $f(x) \approx f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2$.  So let's take the second derivative:

$$f''(x) = \frac{2}{9}(1-x)^{-5/3}$$
$$f''(0) = \frac{2}{9}$$

So, we have $f(x) \approx 1 - \frac{1}{3}x + \frac{1}{9}x^2$.  Let's constrain that quadratic error term.

$$\frac{2}{9}x^2 < \frac{1}{10}$$
$$x^2 < \frac{9}{20}$$
$$|x| < \sqrt{\frac{9}{20}} = \frac{3 \sqrt 5}{10} \approx 0.67082$$

Which turns out not to be too bad of an approximation.  In fact, if you solve $\left| g(x) - f(x) \right| < 0.1$ numerically, you get:

$$-1.20434<x<0.706649$$

You coincidentally also get a bonus interval with the same absolute accuracy.

$$8.59769<x<9.39786$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The domain of a cube root function is all real numbers.

Firstly the inequality is solved incorrectly. If you wanted to multiply by -3 on both sides, f(x) would be -3f(x) on both sides of the inequality. Also since you multiplied by a negative you would need to flip your signs.

The answer:

F(x) takes on all real values of x, so it can be "ignored".

$$ -0.1 < 1- \frac 1 3x <  0.1 $$

Subtract 1,

$$ -1.1 < - \frac 1 3x <  -.9 $$

Multiply by -3 (and flip inequality signs),

$$ 2.7<x<3.3$$

is your restricted domain.

Comment: Thank you for spotting my mistakes. Look, I don't trust your results.  I decided to look at the problem with a graphing calculator and I'm seeing that the interval should be something like that $-1.2 < x < 0.7$.  That doesn't seem compatible with your answer.  Do you understand what's going on here?  I can't see any flaw in your reasoning either.

Comment: Why can the values of $f(x)$ be "ignored"?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack. This needs to be explained: "*F(x) takes on all real values of x, so it can be "ignored"*."

Comment: Hm I'm not completely sure. I assumed that since a function with a restriction-less domain is being added to a finite value, it follows that it has no bearing on the inequality, since any real number of x can be substituted into the inequality to make it true.

Answer (score 0):

Graph f(x), f(x) + 0.1, f(x) - 0.1, and g(x) = 1 - x/3. You'll notice the line g(x) crosses f(x) + 0.1 three times, and f(x) - 0.1 once. Your solution intervals are those two areas where g(x) lies inside of f(x) +/- 0.1.

Find the x coordinates of those four points by setting g(x) equal to f(x) + 0.1 and to f(x) - 0.1. Then create the two interval parts of your solution using those four x coordinates.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).